# How do you enable promiscuous mode in VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

Say I have some virtual machines in a private network inside VMware Workstation, and they're all running Windows 7. I want to enable promiscuous mode on one of these machine's virtual adapter but there's no instructions out there!

There's clear and easy instructions on how to do it on VMware ESXi: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004099

But no instructions on how to do it on VMware Workstation are anywhere to be found.

Comment: Are you running on a Windows or Linux host?  Perhaps https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=287 or https://communities.vmware.com/thread/474611 help?

Comment: Here is your answer: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-089D2595-26C5-433B-9DA4-D2A94C63B7B5.html based on my research the Windows version of Workstation doesn't support promiscuous mode

Answer (score 2):

Shut down the VMWare host.
Locate the VMX file associated with it.
Edit the file and locate the Ethernet section.
Add a new entry for each Ethernet you want to be in promiscuous mode:

```
ethernet%d.noPromisc = "FALSE"
```

(replace `%d` with the ethernet number)

Start the machine and the interface will now operate in promiscuous mode.

[Source](https://s3.amazonaws.com/virtuallyghetto-download/hidden_vmx_params.html)